# How to define the object that the selective search algorithm need to detect

Tags: image-processing, deep-learning

Currently, I am trying to generate annotations "Bounding Box" for object detections with a deep neural network "RCNN", the problem is that I need to do it by hand, I have more than 500 images, and I want to generate the annotations automatically, for that I founded the "Selective Search Algorithm", but what I don't understant is how can I tell to my algorithm what label is correponding foreach generated bounding box

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Look at the paper "Selective Search for Object Recognition". The author has provided the way to generate labels. You have to construct a classifier and train the classifier to get the labels. Hope this helps.